# Installing unity8 on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: unity8

I Want to install unity desktop 8 on my Ubuntu.

Unity 8:
[image: Unity desktop]
Gnome Desktop:
[image: Gnome Desktop]

I used Ubuntu 20.04, but I upgraded it to 20.10.

please if you know any solution . help me to install it

Comment: Please include the images directly into your question.

Comment: Please add the output of `dpkg -l | grep -i unity` with `apt-cache policy unity` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 8 is not developed or supported by canonical any more.
https://unity8.io/

Lomiri, a fork of unity8,  which is developed by the UBports community mainly for use on phones is not considered stable on the desktop. (off-topic: It works nice on the phone and on the tablet though).

The [github](https://github.com/ubports/unity8) page provides instructions for building on Ubuntu 18.04, though there is no mention of newer Ubuntu versions.

Unity7 can be installed by installing the package ubuntu-unity-desktop

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

As of October 2021, the Unity7 Maintainers team along with Ubuntu Unity is maintaining Unity7 for the latest versions of Ubuntu. (thank you @RudraSaraswat).

Comment: Slightly hijacking your knowledge: could you share similar insights about Unity 7 availability for Ubuntu 20.04 and beyond, if you have the info, please?

Comment: @Levente Unity7 is still instalable on Ubuntu 20.04 and on 21.04 (the package is called ubuntu-unity-desktop). There is even an unofficial Ubuntu derivative with the Unity desktop environment as a standard (https://ubuntuunity.org/). However, I do not know who maintains it.

Comment: @Bruni FYI, I'm the maintainer of Ubuntu Unity (and the Unity7 Maintainers team along with Ubuntu Unity is maintaining Unity7 for the latest versions of Ubuntu)